# Are there famous adventurers on the site?

Tags: discussion, topics

On StackOverflow I always get a warm little feeling inside when the Skeet answers my question.

Likewise, it would be a great honor to have a question here answered by e.g. Les Stroud, Cody Lundin, Bear Grylls, etc :-)

So do you know of any member of the site <strike>with an already proven reputation</strike> who is famous (from TV/Books/etc) in the field of adventuring?

Comment: What qualifies as "proven reputation?" I just spent the evening talking with some talented mountaineers who have trekked professionally around the world... But you have never heard of them. I would choose them over Bear Grylls for my team any day.

Comment: Good point @LBell, I may have misphrased my last sentence as this question is really only about people being famous from TV/Books/... I will edit my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The beta's only been going a week or two, and as far as I'm aware Bear Grylls hasn't signed up yet..!

Comment: But if you know him, please do try and get him on here ;)

Comment: We have been talking about drinking our own piss though, so he might show up to discuss that :p